# What is relevant to android.app.Service in WindowPhone 7

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, multitasking

I'm trying to make a stopwatch & countdown app for WindowPhone 7 using Silverlight for WindowPhone SDK and trying to make it run in background when it's tombstoned. In Android, I can use android.app.Service to run it in background. According to [MS AppHub Quickstart](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Running_your_App_in_the_Background_%28Tombstoning%29), "The Windows Phone operating system doesn't allow any third-party applications to run in the background". Please help me if you have any idea for keeping the countdown running when a phone call is received or the phone goes to sleep. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, once your app is tombstoned, your app cannot continue with any custom processes such as having your countdown continue. The Mango SDK coming out this month allows for a bit more freedom in this respect.
If, however, you want to run your app under a lock screen, this is possible. You can simply do this:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Jaime Rodriguez has a great post on running under a lock screen which you can [read here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/01/running-a-windows-phone-application-under-the-lock-screen.aspx).

Until Mango comes out, there's no way to have your program run in the background.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take it in consideration.

Answer (score 1):

As keyboardP notes, you can't continue your process on the phone.

However you could use a server and Toast message popups to still notify the user. It requires more setup and a server to run against, but it will meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have seen with other people making apps like this is to store the time that app was tombstoned and then, when the app is reactivated to look at the difference between the current time and the saved time and deduct that from the countdown.

This may or may not be appropriate, depending on your requirements but may be something to consider.

Comment: Great technique. I've not thought about that. Thanks.